# List all Google Apps Profiles on PHP Site

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-profiles-api

I am trying to get a list of all Google Apps users of a domain onto a public PHP website (without visitors of the site needing to login or do anything). I have a basic understanding of what needs to happen but can't quite piece it all together. It can't be as hard as it seems to me... could it?

**Authentication and Authorization:**
I'm pretty sure it needs to use *OAuth 2.0* ... but am unsure whether it needs *2 legged* or *3 legged*. I got another section of the site working with ClientLogin but that won't pull in Google Apps profiles, only user's first and last names (I need the other profile fields). I have set up the API access within the account and have that side of things all set (I believe).

I have found this page, which shows how to construct a URL request to get all Profiles (in every language except PHP of course) but don't understand how to implement this.
http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/profiles/developers_guide.html

I also tried this example but it just gives me a 401 after I enter the credentials. http://gdatatips.blogspot.com/2008/11/2-legged-oauth-in-php.html

I don't know which frameworks or includes are needed to accomplish this either. I have tried zend, OAuth.php and a whole bunch of other bootstraps... but keep getting lost as to what each is doing.

If someone could help me by outlining:

1. Which files/framework I need to upload and include as a bootstrap
2. What variables within those files I need to update with the Google credentials
3. How I integrate the Google Profiles "Retrieve all Profiles" request with PHP

An *ELI5* (explain it like i'm 5) overview would be *very* much appreciated... I'm sorry for my apparent incompetence, but I have been reading articles for nearly a week and have not gotten anywhere.

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: In the OAuth process you'll need to redirect users to a google page in order for them to grant you the appropriate permissions. But you don't want to require visitors to login in any way?! please explain

Comment: Correct, I'd like to have users visit the page and see the data (without being redirected) ... the authentication would take place behind the scenes. If the domain is mine, shouldn't I be able to display it's info on my site without asking website users to login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question.

You'll need to implement the Google OAuth 2.0 process as it's described [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html) (experimental?), because someone (**you**) will need to give your app the initial permissions to access Google Apps API. Steps are:

- Register your domain with google (don't remember the link)
- Redirect/send browser to an authentication url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth, with the appropriate request params (see the first link). You'll need `access_type=offline`, your scope would be https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/
- Get a code back, then exchange for a **refresh_token**, an **access_token**, and a value specifying when the access_token will **expire**. Store these in a database
- Whenever you need to make an API call, check if your access_token has expired or not, and refresh when necessary, which is what the refresh_token is for. The refresh_token is valid as long as you don't revoke the access you gave to the app.

[OAuth Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/) helps a lot. Good luck.